# Double sink clogged in mobile home

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Was working through a clogged sink yesterday, had a partial flow, went to my parents for a bit, came back to find husband and roommate had decided to take it into their own hands, got some bleach smelling chemical and a plunger and there was no longer a partial flow. I should also mention we have a septic tank.

Watched this video: https://youtu.be/JeurinbyqhQ

Removed pea trap and confirmed clog isn’t there. The rest of my pipes differ from the video so I’m not sure how much I should remove. I was able to get a drain snake in the horizontal part but was unable to go down. There is a little thing near the bottom, black plug with a square twist thing. Not sure if it okay to remove that.

[image: sink picture]

[image: circle with square knob thing]
[image: Side view]

Update, took the access plug thing out. Clog seems to be below that. 
[image]

Post two snakes. First snake made the water go down to where I could just see it. After second snake I can’t see the water. Our plumber previously gave us some Bio-Clean drain cleaner. Going to close everything up and treat the pipes with that, see where we stand after a few hours of that sitting.

[image: after two snakes]

Comment: I am not sure what i am looking at in your photo. Can you move the bucket and take a couple of shots that show more and the part you are unsure of. Right side up please. When was  the last time you septic tank was pumped?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Added more pictures. It kept rotating my pictures to horizontal when I sized them so I took new landscape picture. I have reattached the pea trap for now and poured hot water in since I found a lot of grease when I detached the pea trap.

Comment: The square thing is a clean out plug for exactly your situation. You remove the plug ( unscrew it ) so you can get a snake in and down. Never put grease in pluming? If your snake is not getting the job done you may need a more robust one, you can rent one at a tool rental place, That said it may not be something that can be cleared with an auger, it may be to do whit the septic tank? snake as far as you can and report back.

Comment: Got the plug out, took a bit because I couldn’t find a wrench and had to fashion one. Looks like the clog is below the access. We have a drum auger. Going to try to use it but worried it might be time to call a plumber.

Comment: This thing says 15 feet but how far is it safe to send this snake down?

Comment: There is no danger in going the 15', sometimes you can not go to far because of to many turns in the pipes. If it stops, work in and out while turning in case it is a clog. It should not damage the plumbing.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was able to establish partial flow. I either found a bend or a clog, but the water level did go down. Put some bio cleaner from my plumber in. Says to sit for at least 8 hours so I'll see how it looks in the morning. If still not good I'll snake it again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: While it has the capability to catch spherical legumes it's actually called a pee trap after the letter "P" because it has a shape like a letter P lying on its face.